Changing text colors in Jupyter terminal
I am taking a class with Red Hat, and they have provided a JupyterLab terminal as an interface to our Linux VM's. I am using the dark theme, which is bright white font on top of a black background. I want to change the font color in the terminal only. The Advanced settings allow me to change the size but not the color.
I was actually able to change ALL the font colors by doing the following; note that I am in a Red Hat-provided Virtual Machine so forgive the weird path:
vi /opt/app-root/share/jupyter/lab/themes/@jupyterlab/theme-dark-extension/index.css

And modifying the 255,255,255 in these font colors so that they are a nice orange, just the way I like it:
/* Defaults use Material Design specification */
--jp-ui-font-color0: rgba(255, 128, 64, 1);
--jp-ui-font-color1: rgba(255, 128, 64, 0.87);
--jp-ui-font-color2: rgba(255, 128, 64, 0.54);
--jp-ui-font-color3: rgba(255, 128, 64, 0.38);

The thing is, I've now changed every single bit of text: menus, folders, terminal text, the works.
This is fine because I want my terminal to be orange I don't care that I changed the other stuff. But I wonder- is there a finer-grained way to do this?

Adding screenshots might make your question easier to answer.
